# Method SessionHelper::write does not exist Error

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to use sessions in my CakePHP 2.3 application.  When I add this to my View:

```
           $this->Session->write('key','value');
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning (512): Method SessionHelper::write does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 179]
```

I have tried adding this to my controller:

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery"),"Session");
public $components = array('RequestHandler','Session');
```

But the error still occurs.  Anyone know what is going on?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery"),"Session");
```

to

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js'=>array("Jquery"),"Session");
```

Also, I would recommend doing all session writing login in the controller, not in the view. The view is intended just to display things. So avoid it if you can.

Comment: if you can access session data directly, what is the reason behind your recommendation on setting the session variable in the controller and then passing it to the view? just curious....

Comment: Cake follows the MVC pattern (some might say it doesn't), so the views are there just to display info, a good MVC pattern wouldn't make any variable / logic function in the view, the controller should handle that. You can, because the API let you, but I find it good practice to try and stick as close to the mvc pattern if possible. At the very least, set the "write" of the variable in the controller and just do a `$this->Session->read('var')` in the view.

Comment: gotcha! thats my point though..if you can access it through $this->Session->read('var') directly from the view, there shouldn't be any reason to set it in the controller. except you want to use the variable in the helper and you are worried the Session state might change along the process etc etc

Comment: I guess I'm not really seeing your point. The reason for set it in the controller is just because it adjust to the pattern of cake, as much as the answer for "why not read all the data from a table from the view if you can?", well, just because it doesn't follow the patterns. For me, *any* definition of variables should be done in the controller, and the view must just access its values and display them. Just because cake lets you do it it means if follows best practices. Of course, if following patterns makes you jump through hoops to do a simple thing, you can bypass it or change patterns.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html):

> The major difference between the Session Helper and the Session Component is that the helper does *not* have the ability to write to the session.

and so there is no `write()` method available in the SessionHelper (which you can also see in the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-SessionHelper.html)).